# When trying to generate a Javadoc for my program I get the error message 'use of default constructor, which does not provide a comment' What is wrong?

Tags: java, javadoc

The issue seems to be with the tester class, though I don't understand what exactly the issue is or what to change. It doesn't interfere with how the program runs or functions, but i need the Javadoc in order to submit the assignment.

I have tried altering, adding, and removing the comments for the CalculatorTester class which seems to be the issue, but each change has only produced separate issues without actually resolving the original.

This is the object used for the calculator program. No Javadoc issues here

```
/**
 * A Calculator Object
 * 
 * @author wesal
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Calculator {
    double numone;
    double numtwo;
    double added;
    double subtracted;
    double multiplied;
    double divided;
    int exponential;
    
    /**
    * This object stores the pair of number used in the calculations
    *
    * @param num1 The storage of the first number
    * @param num2 The storage of the second number
    */
    public Calculator(double num1, double num2){       
        numone = num1;
        numtwo = num2;
    }
    
    /**
    * This method adds the pair of numbers stored in the Calculator object
    * @return The result of the two added numbers
    */
    public double add(){
        added = numone + numtwo;
        return added;
    }
    
    /**
    * This method subtracts the second number from the first
    * @return The result of the subtraction operation
    */
    public double subtract(){
        subtracted = numone - numtwo;
        return subtracted;
    }
    
    /**
    * This method multiplies the two numbers together
    * @return The result of the multiplication operation
    */
    public double multiply(){
        multiplied = numone * numtwo;
        return multiplied;
    }
    
    /**
    * This method divides the first number by the second
    * @return The result of the division operation
    */
    public double divide(){
        divided = numone / numtwo;
        return divided;
    }
    
    /**
    * This method takes the integer value of the two numbers 
    * through typecasting and raises the first to the power of 
    * the second
    * 
    * @return The value result of the Math.pow operation
    */
    public int power(){
        exponential = (int) Math.pow((int) numone, (int) numtwo);
        return exponential;
    }
    
    
}
```

This is the tester class causing the Javadoc error, notably `public class CalculatorTester{}`

```
/**
 * A Calculator 
 * 
 * @author wesal
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class CalculatorTester{  
    
    /**
     * The main of the function, where the executable code is written
     * 
     * @param args The command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double num1;
        double num2;

        /**
        * This segment prints out the text asking for user entry as well as accepting and storing the requested input
        */
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: " );
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        num1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: " );
        num2 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(" ");

        /**
        * This constructs the new calculator object with the entered data stored
        */
        Calculator calc = new Calculator(num1,num2);
        
        /**
        * This segment calls back to the methods for the mathematical operations and prints the results
        */
        System.out.println("The Arithmetic Opreations Results: ");
        System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + calc.add());
        System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + calc.subtract());
        System.out.println(num1 + " * " + num2 + " = " + calc.multiply());
        System.out.println(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + calc.divide());
        System.out.println((int) num1 + " ^ " + (int) num2 + " = " + calc.power());

    }
}
```

Comment: This is nothing that Java or JavaDoc enforces. You should ask your instructor how the assignment is intended to be handed in. Everything else is just guessing: add the parameterless constructor manually and add a JavaDoc, add a private parameterless constructor so the (tester) class cannot be instantiated, etc. We really can't know, because we don't know what your assignment checker is checking.

Comment: Add the error text.

Comment: This diagnostic seems to be new in Java 21; it gets issued because `CalculatorTester` specifies no explicit constructor. That means that if code does `new CalculatorTester()`, no JavaDoc is available. As @knittl suggests, add an explicit default constructor, either as `private` (seems to be applicable here - your class only acts as a container for the `main` method), or as public with appropriate JavaDoc for it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building javadoc with the `-Xdoclint` flag? You could avoid doing that, or perhaps specify something like `-Xdoclint:all,-missing`.

https://github.com/plume-lib/require-javadoc discusses how to avoid this while requiring other javadoc features.